# Joining with cross-reference table in hibernate and spring

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

I use hibernate and spring-data. There are two tables with many-to-many relationship.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FirstEntity")
public class FirstEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "first_entity_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "first_entiry_name")
    private String name;

    /* getters and setters are below*/
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "SecondEntity")
public class SecondEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "second_entity_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "second_entiry_name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "second_entiry_desc")
    private String description;

    /* getters and setters are below*/
}
```

And entity for cross-reference table.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FirstSecondEntity")
public class FirstSecondEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "first_second_entity_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "first_entity_id")
    private Long firstEntityId;

    @Column(name = "second_entity_id")
    private Long secondEntityId;

    /* getters and setters are below*/
}
```

I need SELECT like this

```
SELECT FirstEntity.name, SecondEntity.name, SecondEntity.description FROM SecondEntity INNER JOIN FirstSecondEntity ON SecondEntity.id = FirstSecondEntity.secondEntityId INNER JOIN User ON FirstEntity.id = FirstSecondEntity.firstEntityId
```

i.e. I need all records from cross-reference table where instead of ids there is actual info from entities.
Inserting this query into @Query annotation in my CrudRepository-extended class doesn't work because of

```
ERROR [main][org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter]  Path expected for join!
```

So I need your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your join table is all screwed up.  In this case, you actually don't even need the join table as a hibernate mapping:

In Second Entity add the following list:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "FirstSecondEntity",
        joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "first_entity_id",
                        nullable = false,
                        updatable = false) },
        inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "second_entity_id",
                        nullable = false,
                        updatable = false) },
        )
private List<FirstEntity> firstEntities;
```

In FirstEntity add the following list:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        mappedBy = "firstEntities")
private List<SecondEntity> secondEntities;
```

Comment: And the query should be left the same and added to @Query annotation?  If yes, I got exception.

ERROR [main][org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter]  Path expected for join!

Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: Unable to resolve path [FirstEntity.name], unexpected token [FirstEntity] [SELECT FirstEntity.name as firstName, SecondEntity.name as secondName, SecondEntity.description as description FROM SecondEntity INNER JOIN FirstSecondEntity ON SecondEntity.id = FirstSecondEntity.secondEntityId INNER JOIN User ON FirstEntity.id = FirstSecondEntity.firstEntityId]

Comment: No the query needs to change, that is an SQL query, you need to write an HQL query.  You will usually be returning entity objects.

Comment: So I should create a new entity with necessary fields to return from query?